# sql update - access to the current row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, subquery

I would like update the column [ACIdent] from the table [Values].
With the subquery i try to get an ID from the same table.

On the point **???** i try to access to the column [PathName] of the respective row of the update script. But this solution doesn't work.

How can i do this? Many thanks in advance!

```
Update [Values]
Set ACIdent = 

(Select  b.valueIdent  From Values as b Where b.SampleIdent = 0 and b.PathName = ???Values.PathName)
  
Where ValueIdent= 614
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restructure your query a bit so you can alias the table.

```
Update v
Set ACIdent = 

(Select  b.valueIdent  From Values as b Where b.SampleIdent = 0 and b.PathName = v.PathName)

From [Values] v
Where v.ValueIdent= 614
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the problem!

Comment: Which dbms is this for?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server